# Can a server have 2 different sets of nameservers?

Tags: nameserver

So I have domain1.com and domain2.com, they are both independant of each other.

Now domain1.com has NS setup as ns1.domain1.com and ns2.domain1.com which is also setup on the server.

I want to setup domain2 on the same server, but can I create another set of nameservers for this domain? i.e. ns1.domain2.com & ns2.domain2.com which points to the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this.

It's not necessarily a great idea, though. Using one set of nameserver addresses lets you move those nameservers onto different IPs while only having to change them in one place (instead of, say, updating thousands of different domains' custom nameserver addresses).

It's also pretty unnecessary, as are whitelabeled nameserver addresses in general. People don't routinely see them, and anyone who knows their way around `whois` probably doesn't really care.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be a DNS expert...
But I like to experiment, so have had many domains that I registered.
I have just one DNS server that handles my xyz.com domain. I call it ns.xyz.com (names have been changed, just for example.)

When I register a new domain, I then point its nameserver to ns.xyz.com, also.
And I setup a new zone on my DNS to match.

I recently moved my DNS to an outside service, so I don't have to deal with this so much.